# Changing Wordpress Contact form 7 text area row and column value

Tags: wordpress, textarea

Default Text area layout in contact form 7 is [textarea your-message 40x10 "your message here ..."]. This means 40 column and 10 row.

So, to change the default value just change the row and column value 40x10.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to change the textarea row and column use:

```
[textarea* message id:contact-message 10x2 placeholder "Your Message"]
```

For you example, 40x10 means 40 columns and 10 rows.

Hope it answers your dilemma.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First parameter is the Columns (cols) and Second parameter is the rows (rows) respectively. 40x10 express 40 columns and 10 rows respectively.

Refer to [this](https://contactform7.com/text-fields/#textarea) for more regarding `textarea` field.